# OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104, address = storage.googleapis.com, prort = 37890

Tags: flutter, dart

When I get Flutter Dependency Packages form pub.dev site then it not to install show below this  this error...

[image]

And My Flutter Doctor is...

[image]

Details Description Issue here:
[flutter issue for dependencies installation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48175#issue-545285371)

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

### You are trying to connect to https, while the server is http.

use http 'in the link' and add this line to `AndroidManifest.xml` to allow `http package` to connect to server that are not secure

```
<application

        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be your ISP blocking the connection. Can you access to https://pub.dartlang.org ?

Maybe a simple `flutter clean` might solve the issue. If not, you can also try `flutter pub cache repair`.

Comment: yes i can access https://pub.dartlang.org this site  @MickaelHrndz

Comment: Try `sudo apt install net-tools`

Comment: try running `flutter packages get` again. If the error persists, check [these similar issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26935#issuecomment-456745678) on GitHub.

Comment: when I Run  `flutter pub cache repair` the same issue show like -

Failed to repair archive 2.0.11. Error:
SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104, address = storage.googleapis.com, port = 39460  @MickaelHrndz

Comment: I already Run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub cache repair`

Answer (score 4):

Yes Servers hosting the Flutter SDK components blocked in my country (Bangladesh). I used vpn for USA IP address then it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happened, because the request url (uri) was too long. The backend closed the connection directly with the message "Connection reset by peer".

Solution: Send large data within the body field (not inside headers).

Comment: Are you talking about too many parameters in the url when you say "url (uri) was too long"?

Comment: No more like that the data normally sent through body was located in the url leading to this exception